# jQuery get functions response is OK but fail function is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a jQuery get function and the response is the expected result. But not the success, but the fail function is triggered.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#placeOrderForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // AJAX call
            jQuery.get(
                '/checkout/multi/get-payment-url',
                jQuery(this).serialize(),
                "GET"
            ).done(function( data ) {
                alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log( "error" );
                console.log( data );
            })
            .always(function(data) {
                console.log( "finished" );
                console.log( data );
            });
        });
    });
```

Response status is `status: 200`  and `statusText: "OK"`.
Where can I see the actual error that might occur, and how can I fix it?

Part of the response:

```
abort: function abort()​
always: function always()​
catch: function catch()​
done: function add()​
fail: function add()​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()​
pipe: function pipe()​
progress: function add()​
promise: promise()
length: 1
name: "promise"
prototype: Object { … }
<prototype>: function ()
readyState: 4
responseText: "\"https://wpp-test.wirecard.com/?wPaymentToken=xyz""
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()​
state: function state()
status: 200
statusCode: function statusCode()
statusText: "OK"
then: function then()​
<prototype>: {…
```

Comment: Are *any* errors displayed in the `console`?

Comment: try debugging the response in browser debugger, you will see the actual error

Comment: What is the Content-Type of the response? What is the body of the response?

Comment: i pasted the console output in the text. i don't get any error in console but a warning that says:
Strict-Transport-Security: The connection to the site is untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored.[Learn More]